# HiQPdf Merge documents in one pdf and then applay paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiqpdf

Does anyone have an idea how to enable paging after adding two documents in HiQPdf?

Here is my code for adding documents:

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfPotrate = htmlToPdf;
htmlToPdfPotrate.Document.PageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Landscape;
PdfDocument pdfDoc1 = htmlToPdfPotrate.ConvertHtmlToPdfDocument(NptHtml, null);
htmlToPdf.Document.PageOrientation = PageOrientation;
PdfDocument pdfDoc2 = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlToPdfDocument(ResponsiblePartyAndNptTypeChart, null);
pdfDocument.AddDocument(pdfDoc1);
pdfDocument.AddDocument(pdfDoc2);
```

How to enable paging?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the 2 HTML documents to PDF like in [Add Many HTML Documents to Same PDF Document](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertManyHtmlToPdf.aspx) example. In that sample you have the option to add a footer with page numbering to resulted PDF document. See the C# code for this:

```
protected void buttonCreatePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create an empty PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    // add a page to document
    PdfPage page1 = document.AddPage(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfDocumentMargins(5), PdfPageOrientation.Portrait);

    try
    {
        // set the document header and footer before adding any objects to document
        SetHeader(document);
        SetFooter(document);

        // layout the HTML from URL 1
        PdfHtml html1 = new PdfHtml(textBoxUrl1.Text);
        html1.WaitBeforeConvert = 2;
        PdfLayoutInfo html1LayoutInfo = page1.Layout(html1);

        // determine the PDF page where to add URL 2
        PdfPage page2 = null;
        System.Drawing.PointF location2 = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
        if (checkBoxNewPage.Checked)
        {
            // URL 2 is laid out on a new page with the selected orientation
            page2 = document.AddPage(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfDocumentMargins(5), GetSelectedPageOrientation());
            location2 = System.Drawing.PointF.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            // URL 2 is laid out immediately after URL 1 and html1LayoutInfo
            // gives the location where the URL 1 layout finished
            page2 = document.Pages[html1LayoutInfo.LastPageIndex];
            location2 = new System.Drawing.PointF(html1LayoutInfo.LastPageRectangle.X, html1LayoutInfo.LastPageRectangle.Bottom);
        }

        // layout the HTML from URL 2
        PdfHtml html2 = new PdfHtml(location2.X, location2.Y, textBoxUrl2.Text);
        html2.WaitBeforeConvert = 2;
        page2.Layout(html2);

        // write the PDF document to a memory buffer
        byte[] pdfBuffer = document.WriteToMemory();

        // inform the browser about the binary data format
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // let the browser know how to open the PDF document and the file name
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=LayoutMultipleHtml.pdf; size={0}",
                    pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

        // write the PDF buffer to HTTP response
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);

        // call End() method of HTTP response to stop ASP.NET page processing
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        document.Close();
    }
}

private void SetFooter(PdfDocument document)
{
    if (!checkBoxAddFooter.Checked)
        return;

    //create the document footer
    document.CreateFooterCanvas(50);

    // layout HTML in footer
    PdfHtml footerHtml = new PdfHtml(5, 5, @"<span style=""color:Navy; font-family:Times New Roman; font-style:italic"">
                    Quickly Create High Quality PDFs with </span><a href=""http://www.hiqpdf.com"">HiQPdf</a>", null);
    footerHtml.FitDestHeight = true;
    footerHtml.FontEmbedding = true;
    document.Footer.Layout(footerHtml);


    float footerHeight = document.Footer.Height;
    float footerWidth = document.Footer.Width;

    // add page numbering
    System.Drawing.Font pageNumberingFont = new System.Drawing.Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 8, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
    PdfText pageNumberingText = new PdfText(5, footerHeight - 12, "Page {CrtPage} of {PageCount}", pageNumberingFont);
    pageNumberingText.HorizontalAlign = PdfTextHAlign.Center;
    pageNumberingText.EmbedSystemFont = true;
    pageNumberingText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
    document.Footer.Layout(pageNumberingText);

    string footerImageFile = Server.MapPath("~") + @"\DemoFiles\Images\HiQPdfLogo.png";
    PdfImage logoFooterImage = new PdfImage(footerWidth - 40 - 5, 5, 40, System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(footerImageFile));
    document.Footer.Layout(logoFooterImage);

    // create a border for footer
    PdfRectangle borderRectangle = new PdfRectangle(1, 1, footerWidth - 2, footerHeight - 2);
    borderRectangle.LineStyle.LineWidth = 0.5f;
    borderRectangle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
    document.Footer.Layout(borderRectangle);
}
```

Comment: There is also a blog post about [converting multiple HTML to PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20170705085725/https://hiqpdf-html-to-pdf.com/2016/06/22/adding-many-html-documents-to-the-same-pdf-document/) where you can find more details about this approach.

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use the PdfHtmlWithPlaceHolders class:**

```
 // add page numbers in HTML - more flexible but less efficient than text version
                    PdfHtmlWithPlaceHolders htmlWithPageNumbers = new PdfHtmlWithPlaceHolders(5, footerHeight - 20,
                        "Page <span style=\"font-size: 16px; color: blue; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold\">
                        {CrtPage}</span> of 
                        <span style=\"font-size: 16px; color: green; font-weight: bold\">{PageCount}</span>", null);
                    htmlToPdfDocument.Footer.Layout(htmlWithPageNumbers);
```